Is there a best practice for naming function arguments that have the same name as a global variable?
I frequently find myself wondering if there is any best practice for the following situation.
Let's say, I want to access local files within my Python script and, therefore, create a global variable path pointing at the dataset.
Now I'm writing a function which should have a path variable as an argument.
I know that the local variable within the function shadows the global variable but I just find it unsatisfying to write path=path.
I think I remember seeing that people just write an underscore before the local variable like in _path=path.
Is that a thing?
Is there any best practice?
How do you name your function arguments that have the same name as a global argument?
Best
Jo

Global variables should generally have more descriptive names. E.g. default_path. Then you would write def myfunc(path=default_path):. Also, remember that the default value is evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So are you sure you want to use that variable as the default in the first place?

This question is likely to be closed because we don't answer "best practice" questions. Unless there's a written standard (e.g. PEP-8), it's just individual opinion.

This is a matter of opinion. Personally, I distinguish globals by naming them in all uppercase bearing in mind that Python variable names are case-sensitive

I would consider it best practice to make global vars SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE and/or to pack 'em into a dict if there's any significant count
PATH_DEFAULT = pathlib.Path("/my_path")
CONFIG = {
    "path": pathlib.Path("/my_path"),
}

However, I'd also consider it bad practice to set default args this way as they'll be evaluated once at runtime, while outer features may want to set them to something else .. instead (especially with a class), set the default to None and then look it up at runtime instead if argname is None: ...
for example
>>> ARG = 1
>>> def test(arg=ARG):
...     print(arg)
... 
>>> ARG = 2
>>> test()
1

changed to look up the default whenever called
>>> ARG = 1
>>> def test(arg=None):
...     if arg is None:
...         arg = ARG
...     print(arg)
... 
>>> test()
1
>>> ARG = 2
>>> test()
2

more complete example for a class
class Foo:
    path_default = pathlib.Path("/my_path")
    def __init__(self, path=None, *args):
        if path is None:
            path = self.path_default

